# Заново создающиеся компоненты при смене url на react-router-4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, ecmascript

Добрый день или вечер.

Есть такой код.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import reactDom from 'react-dom';

import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

import RootComponent from './ui/root/RootComponent.jsx';

import {defaultSettings, urlSettings} from './config/settings';

import {ajaxQuery, createUrlLink as CUL} from './core/coreUtils';

import AboutComponent from './ui/modules/AboutComponent.jsx';
import UsersComponent from './ui/modules/UsersComponent.jsx';
import NotFoundComponent from './ui/modules/NotFoundComponent.jsx';

const rootDomComponent = document.getElementById('root');

let globalEvents = null;

ajaxQuery({
        url: CUL(defaultSettings, urlSettings['getCommonData'])
    },{
        afterSuccess: (result) => {

            let {data = {}} = result;
            let {
                user = {},
                headers = []
            } = data;

            reactDom.render((
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <RootComponent
                        serverData={data}
                        globalEvents={globalEvents}
                    >
                        <Switch>
                            <Route
                                path="/about"
                                cached={true}
                                render={ (props) => <AboutComponent {...props} globalEvents={globalEvents} serverData={data} /> }
                            />
                            <Route
                                path="/users"
                                cache
                                render={ (props) => <UsersComponent {...props} globalEvents={globalEvents} serverData={data} /> }
                            />
                            <Route
                                component={NotFoundComponent}
                            />
                        </Switch>
                    </RootComponent>
                </BrowserRouter>
            ), rootDomComponent);
        },
        afterError: (result) => {
            window.console.log('error:');
            window.console.log(result);
        }
});
```

Если мы зайдем к примеру на /about, потом на /users а затем снова вернемся на /about, то компонент AboutComponent будет создан заново, т.е. выполнится метод constructor.

У меня следующий вопрос - можно ли как-то нативным способом закешировать компонент если он уже был создан, или это сделать никак нельзя и надо лепить костыли?

Заранее благодарю за помощь.